# How to convert XML to SQL?

Tags: mysql, xml

I have an XML file, with a schema defined in it.
The scheme has several nested elements (e.g., Family (root) -> Family Members (list of sub-nodes) ).

What would be the easiest way to break this down to a mysql database with multiple tables? Preferably an automated tool/GUI to handle this process. I am trying to avoid writing dedicated code to parse the file and extract the data, an approach that was common in other related questions.

I am using a mac, so windows tools are not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

mysql has load xml as a [command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-xml.html) which is quite nice if your data can be formatted to match this specification. It's hard to tell if that would work for your dataset without seeing more.

The first thing you would have to do is create a mysql schema based on the XML schema. There are some [projects](http://xsd2db.sourceforge.net/) to do this, but it's worth noting that not everything that can be described in XSD can be implemented in SQL.

You could use XSLT or regexp or an editor to get what you want, then do an import. If you have to use a DOM [parser](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser) to convert your XML to CSVs to load to mysql, it's not too tough at all.

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially asking how to automate the process of (relational) normalization, and that's very difficult if you're only starting from an instance. For example, if your instance has

```
<book>
  <author>Kay</author>
</book>
```

there's no way of knowing whether a book can have multiple authors, which would affect the SQL table structure.

If you've got a schema then you can do better, but it's still not ideal because inferring the non-hierarchic relationships from an XSD is going to be pretty difficult. Apart from anything else, there are usually cross-document relationships which XSD can't describe - it's unusual to put all your data in one giant XML document.

To do this job properly, you really need to reverse-engineer the object model, and that requires a semantic understanding of the data, not just syntactic manipulation.

Comment: I thought there might be a tool which could extract at least all tables, and let me complete the relations between tables. So following your example, the tool would extract all books and all authors, into two separate tables. And would ask me whether I want to connect them and based on which field/attribute